# Add Firebase image URL to my collection

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have the following method I'm accessing when my VueJS component is loading:

```
getServices () {
  fb.servicesCollection.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    this.serviceList = []
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const { name, icon } = doc.data()
      fb.storage.ref().child(icon).getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
        console.log(url)
      })
      this.serviceList.push({id: doc.id, name: name, icon: 'iconURL'})
    })
    this.isLoading = false
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

What I want to achieve is to get the url to replace the current 'iconURL' string. Didn't find any method to do that in the last couple of hours. Please help!

Comment: It is not 100% clear what you try to achieve. Do you want to replace the value of `icon` (when you push the object to `serviceList` with the result of `getDownloadURL()`? What do you get with `console.log(url)`? The correct urls?

Comment: I do get the URL of the image and I want to add it to my serviceList on icon key.

Comment: And `icon` is a field of the documents contained by the servicesCollection. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is right! I gust want to pass the url returned by Firebase storage to my my icon key in serviceList collection... Can't figure how to do that...

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick. (However note that I could no test it, so it may need a bit of fine tuning... You can report how it works in the comments and we correct it if necessary)

Since you want to execute several `getDownloadURL()` asynchronous calls to Firebase Storage in parallel, you have to use `Promise.all()`, since `getDownloadURL()` returns a promise, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL).

```
getServices () {
  let namesArray = []
  let docIdArray = []
  fb.servicesCollection.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    this.serviceList = []
    let promises = []
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const icon = doc.data().icon;
      promises.push(fb.storage.ref().child(icon).getDownloadURL())
      namesArray.push(doc.data().name)
      docIdArray.push(doc.id)
    })
    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
  .then(results => {
      results.forEach((value, index) => {
        this.serviceList.push({id: docIdArray[index], name: namesArray[index], icon: value})
      })
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it in the end...

```
getServices () {
  fb.servicesCollection.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    this.serviceList = []
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const { name, icon } = doc.data()
      fb.storage.ref(icon).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        this.serviceList.push({id: doc.id, name: name, icon: url})
      })
    })
    this.isLoading = false
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

Thank you for all your efforts to help me!!! Highly appreciate it!

Comment: So it means that you have only one document in the servicesCollection, isn't it?